# Is it possible to run javascript before images begin loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I'd like to change the src attribute of images before they are requested by the browser, the aim being to reduce the size of the images using a PHP script like Timthumb. Using jQuery, I thought `$(document).ready` would do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var imgs = $('#container img');
  jQuery.each(imgs, function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="timthumb/timthumb.php?src=' + $(this).attr('src') + '&w=200" />');
    });
});
```

But the original, unresized image is still downloaded in the background to the browser's cache. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do on the client side, or is server-side the only option?

Comment: Why don't you just change the src in the script that generates them instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Javascript loading and execution is serialized by the browser (unless you use something like `head.js`), but the problem is that the DOM has to be available for a script to modify it. The jQuery ready event fires **after** the DOM is available, so the browser has already started requesting the resources that were referenced in the HTML.

So if you put the Javascript before the image tag it won't be able to find the image tags, and once ready fires the download has already started. I'm not aware of any events that fire before image load (just one for aborts), so the cleanest method is to create the HTML with the modified `src` attributes in the first place.

Alternatively, put the `src` in a different attribute on the image (like `data_orig_src`) and run the script to set `src` to `data_orig_src` on each image upon document ready. Use CSS to hide the images before changing the `src` so the user doesn't see a broken image icon. I think this is probably better than adding the images after the fact because you won't need to track where the images need to be placed in the DOM, and it should perform better as well.

Of course if you can change the server to use `data_orig_src` instead of `src`, why not just put the proper `src` in the tag in the first place...

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like server-side is the only way to go. Thanks.

Comment: The only reason I could see for doing what you were asking to do is if you didn't have access to the server code, or modifying it was extremely painful for whatever reason.

Comment: A valid use case example would be implementing background image lazy loading in something like Webflow.

Comment: Note that this answer is over 8 years old and the world has moved on since then. :-) We currently use lazysizes (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) for lazy image loading.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot change the DOM of the page before the DOM has been loaded.  And, once the DOM has been loaded, the browser has already started requesting images.  So, you cannot change `<img>` tags before they start loading their images.

What you could do is change the source of the page to not have any of the images you want to change in the source of the page and then use javascript to dynamically insert the desired images after the page has been loaded.  This way the browser will never request the wrong images.

Or, you could change the `<img>` tags to not have a `.src` property at all and with your Javascript you would add the `.src` property.  An `<img>` tag with no `.src` property will not display until you provide it with a `.src` property.

If you're worried about the wrong images flashing as they are loaded before you change them to the correct images, you can use CSS in a stylesheet to hide the images initially and then after you change the `img.src` to the correct value and that new `.src` value has loaded, you can make them visible.

If you can't change the source of the page, then all you can do is hide the images initially (using CSS) until the correct `.src` has been set on them and that new `.src` value has been loaded.

Comment: Just a note on hiding the images, then changing the img.src after the fact, one problem you might run into is the old image will show briefly while the newer image loads, so you get a bit of a "flash" effect.

Comment: The whole point of hiding the images initially is that the old image won't show.

Comment: Exactly, but if you use css to hide, jquery change the attribute, then show the image, it will flash the old image while the new image loads.

Comment: @HighwayofLife - I tested Safari, IE9 and Chrome and do not see a flash. Firefox does flash (how bogus).  You can show() when the new image is loaded if you want to prevent the flash in Firefox.  Here's a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fgK9q/.

Answer (score 0):

It is sort of possible but not in the way you currently have or probably want and it doesn't degrade gracefully but you can take the image out of your html and use jQuery to insert it into your html and apply whatever changes you want to it.

Example:

```
var image = $('<img />').attr('src', 'imageURL.jpg');
image.appendTo('domElement');
```

But doing it like this it doesn't make any sense to me as to why you wouldn't just edit the image source anyway.